# MongoDB aggregate pipeline: Get smallest value with grouping and multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Please help me write a valid MongoDB aggregate pipeline for the following query:

*Get the minimum votes of the 'lab' party in any area where no more than 5 parties including the 'lab' party had candidates.*

Here's the pipeline I have written:

```js
    pipeline = [
    // stage 1: unwind the nested results
    { $unwind: "$results" },

    // stage 2: group the results by area, get party count
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$area",
            partyCount: {
                $sum: 1
            },
            results: {
                $push: {
                    party: "$results.party"
                    votes: "$results.votes"
                }
            }
        }
    },

    // stage 3: filter by the given party and partyCount <= 5
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                { partyCount: { $lte: 5 } },
                { results.party: "lab" }
            ]
        }
    },

    // stage 4: unwind the results again
    { $unwind: "$results" },

    // stage 5: filter the results now to only include 'lab' party
    {
        $match: { "results.party": "lab" }
    },

    // stage 6: project the results with the area name
    {
        $project: {
            name: "$_id",
            _id: 0,
            "results.party": 1,
            "results.votes": 1
        }
    },

    // stage 7: group the results by the party and get the minimum votes of the 'lab' party
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$results.party",
            minVotes: {
                $min: "$results.votes"
            }
        }
    }]
```

I am not sure if this giving me the correct result and I can't make it to include the area name in the final result as well.

Sample data

```json
        { "num": 27, "area": "basildon", "electors": 56793, "results": [ { "party": "con", "leader": "thatcher", "votes": 17516}, { "party": "lab", "leader": "foot", "votes": 16137}, { "party": "sdp", "leader": "jenkins", "votes": 11634}]}
    { "num": 28, "area": "basingstoke", "electors": 60414, "results": [ { "party": "con", "leader": "thatcher", "votes": 28381}, { "party": "lab", "leader": "foot", "votes": 10646}, { "party": "sdp", "leader": "jenkins", "votes": 15931}, { "party": "bnp", "leader": "tyndall", "votes": 344}]}
    { "num": 29, "area": "bassetlaw", "electors": 61807, "results": [ { "party": "con", "leader": "thatcher", "votes": 18400}, { "party": "lab", "leader": "foot", "votes": 22231}, { "party": "sdp", "leader": "jenkins", "votes": 8124}]}
    { "num": 30, "area": "bath", "electors": 62355, "results": [ { "party": "con", "leader": "thatcher", "votes": 22544}, { "party": "lab", "leader": "foot", "votes": 7259}, { "party": "sdp", "leader": "jenkins", "votes": 17240}, { "party": "eco", "leader": "whittaker", "votes": 441}]}
    { "num": 31, "area": "batley and spen", "electors": 71206, "results": [ { "party": "con", "leader": "thatcher", "votes": 21433}, { "party": "lab", "leader": "foot", "votes": 20563}, { "party": "sdp", "leader": "jenkins", "votes": 11678}, { "party": "eco", "leader": "whittaker", "votes": 493}]}
```

Dataset is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lsa3ke-BTkAknVkrUmi622wYaJjPJMUR/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data as text. 2-3 documents are sufficient, we don't need the full data set.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$match` to get only records with lab
2. `$addFields` 2 auxiliary fields:

   1. `partyCount`: using `$size` to find number of party in that area(assuming no duplicate party result)
   2. `minVote`: use `$reduce` to conditionally find the min vote of lab
3. `$match` by `partyCount` <= 5

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "results.party": "lab"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "partyCount": {
        $size: "$results"
      },
      "minVote": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$results",
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.party",
                      "lab"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $or: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$value",
                          null
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $lt: [
                          "$$this.votes",
                          "$$value"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$this.votes",
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      partyCount: {
        $lte: 5
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XRHVQGTRfqh) for your reference.